# Использование switch и enum

Tags: c++, c

Проблема с enum'ом внутри switch'а.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужен код

```
class unicell : cell
{
    enum type { bacterium, amoeba, infusorium };
public:
    void getchrome()
    {
        cout<<"Chromosome"<<chromosome<<endl;
        switch(type)
        {
        case bacterium:
            cout<<"Bacterium";
            break;
        case amoeba:
            cout<<"Amoeba";
            break;
        case infusorium:
            cout<<"Infusorium";
            break;
        }


    }
};
```

Comment: Что именно вы хотели сказать вот этой загадочной конструкцией `switch(type)`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Глупая ошибка - незнание как работает enum.

```
  enum Type { bacterium, amoeba, infusorium };// здесь был создан тип 
                            //переменной Type, но не сама переменная.
  Type iii;//здесь создается переменная, которую нужно засунуть в switch
```

Правильный код

```
   class unicell : cell
{
    enum Type { bacterium, amoeba, infusorium };
    Type typpe;
public:
    void getchrome()
    {
        cout<<"Chromosome"<<chromosome<<endl;
        switch(typpe)
        {
        case bacterium:
            cout<<"Bacterium";
            break;
        case amoeba:
            cout<<"Amoeba";
            break;
        case infusorium:
            cout<<"Infusorium";
            break;
        };
    }


    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое решение - заменить

```
enum type { bacterium, amoeba, infusorium };
```

на

```
enum { bacterium, amoeba, infusorium } type;
```

:)
Т.е. сделать `type` не названием перечисления, а переменной.